# Como criar gráfico de barras com 2 eixos y diferentes e o mesmo eixo x?

Tags: python, data, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

Estou tentando traçar um gráfico de barras com 2 eixos y diferentes e o mesmo eixo x.

O mais próximo que cheguei do sucesso com o seguinte código:

```
fig = plt.figure() # Create matplotlib figure

ax = fig.add_subplot(111) # Create matplotlib axes
ax2 = ax.twinx() # Create another axes that shares the same x-axis as ax.

width = 0.4

final_df['GDP Value'].plot(kind='bar', color='red', ax=ax, width=width, position=1)
final_df['Homicides per 100 people'].plot(kind='bar', color='blue', ax=ax2, width=width, position=0)

ax.set_ylabel('GDP Value')
ax2.set_ylabel('Homicides per 100 people')

plt.show()
```

Mas como vocês podem ver na imagem abaixo o eixo x é o índice do meu DF, mas gostaria que fosse uma coluna específica, chamada 'Nome do País'. Tentei especificá-lo assim:

```
final_df['GDP Value'].plot(x=final_df['Country Name'],kind='bar', color='red', ax=ax, width=width, position=1)
```

Mas não funcionou.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está a estrutura do meu DF:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço antecipadamente, vocês são os melhores.

Answer (score 0):

De uma forma geral, é mais fácil utilizar os objetos `Axes` do módulo `matplotlib.pyplot` diretamente do que tentar plotar com `df.plot` (que nada mais é um "atalho" que o pandas oferece para tentar plotar as coisas por você). Nesse caso, o que você quer é o método `Axes.bar` (que também é acessível via `plt.bar`, caso você já tenha visto essa função por aí).

Você acertou em usar `plt.Axes.twinx` para criar um segundo eixo Y. Faltou apenas usar cada objeto `Axes` para plotar o dado em cada respectivo eixo. Exemplo com uma pequena porção dos seus dados:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Conjunto de dados para teste
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Country Name': ['United States', 'China', 'Japan'],
    'GDP Value': [1.75e+13, 1.05e+13, 4.85e+12],
    'Homicides per 100 people': [4.44, 0.72, 0.31],
})
width = 0.4

# Cria figura com eixo Y na esquerda (padrão), e plota dados nele
figure, left_ax = plt.subplots()
left_ax.bar(df['Country Name'], df['GDP Value'], color='red', width=-width, align='edge')
left_ax.set_ylabel('GDP Value')

# Cria eixo Y na direita e plota dados nele
right_ax = left_ax.twinx()
right_ax.bar(df['Country Name'], df['Homicides per 100 people'], color='blue', width=width, align='edge')
right_ax.set_ylabel('Homicides per 100 people')

# Mostra o gráfico
plt.show()
```

Gráfico gerado:

[image: output]